# Get ConfigObj to quote strings

Tags: python, configobj

If I run the following script:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj()
config.filename = 'test.cfg'
config['keyword1'] = "the value"
config['keyword2'] = "'{0:s}'".format("the value")
config['keyword3'] = '"{0:s}"'.format("the value")
config.write()
```

the output is:

```
keyword1 = the value
keyword2 = "'the value'"
keyword3 = '"the value"'
```

Is there any way to produce the following output?

```
keyword1 = 'the value'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is `unrepr=True`

```
config = ConfigObj(unrepr=True)
```

Then quotes will be preserved when you write back to file.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the ConfigObj module, however from the [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#string-interpolation) it appears that you may be able to achieve this by passing the interpolation argument when instantiating the ConfigObj.

Try:

`config = ConfigObj(interpolation = 'Template')`

or

```
config = ConfigObj(interpolation = False)
```